# laravel 5.1 phpspec command not found

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.1, phpspec

I'm trying to run phpspec but when I do a command `phpspec run` inside root project folder it just prints:

```
-bash: phpspec: command not found
```

But when I do `composer show -i` it shows it's installed (because it's in package.json):

```
phpspec/php-diff                      v1.0.2             A comprehensive li...
phpspec/phpspec                       2.5.3              Specification-orie...
phpspec/prophecy                      v1.6.1             Highly opinionated...
```

What's wrong?

Comment: have you tried `composer update` ?

Comment: yes, it's still not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to add the path to the executable to your `$PATH` or, when you call it...call it by the full path to phpspec (something like `./vendor/bin/phpspec run`)